# Intellij cannot resolve relocated Java imports using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, import

I have relocate in my Gradle project. For example, I have

import org.apache.myproject.relocated.com.google.common.collect.Lists;

My IntelliJ can resolve all the imports but not the relocated ones. I am able to use Gradle build in my terminal but when I run the unit test, it complaints 'cannot resolve the symbols' that are imported via relocates.

Comment: What does *I have relocate in my Gradle project.* mean?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and asked for help on the Gradle Community Slack (no answer yet) https://gradle-community.slack.com/archives/CAH4ZP3GX/p1604604939142000

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I presume he means he relocated classes using the Shadow Plugin https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/.